# How to return to file upload page after successful upload?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form for file upload and its working no problems.
The problem comes when I wish to return to the form after the file upload is complete. The form will not show. I read another post on here that said that i need to use

```
header("Location: upload.php?message=" . $message . "");
```

and so did, however the from is still not showing. What can i do to make this work?

**upload.php:**

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "***********";
    $password = "*********";
    $dbname = "**********";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
      }
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="nav">
     </div>
     <div class="main">
     <div class="content update">
       <?php
         if($_SESSION["logedin"] == "true"){
           $sql = "SELECT * FROM content WHERE ID=" . $_POST["ID"];
           //echo $sql;
           $result = $conn->query($sql);
           while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
             $title=$row["title"];
             $body=$row["body"];
             $id=$row["ID"];
           }
         }
         $breaks = array("<br />","<br>","<br/>","<br />","&lt;br /&gt;","&lt;br/&gt;","&lt;br&gt;");
         //$title = str_ireplace($breaks, "\n", $title);
         //$body = str_ireplace($breaks, "\n", $body);  
         //echo $body;
         echo $_GET['message'];
    ?>

    <form action="doupload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      Name file:
      <input type"text" name="title">
      Select file to upload:
      <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
      <input type="hidden" name="doload" value="doload">
      <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
    </form>
    </div>
    <div class="row2">
      <h2></h2>
      </div>
       <div class="row2">
         <div class="contentbubble">
           <h2 id="demo"></h2>
           <p id="demo2"></p>
         </div>
       </div> 
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**doupload.php**

```
    <?php
     session_start();
      $message="";
      $filename = 'forms/';
      if (file_exists($filename)) {
          //echo "The file $filename exists";
        } else {
          //echo "The file $filename does not exist";
        }

      $servername = "localhost";
      $username = "**********";
      $password = "**********";
      $dbname = "***********";

      // Create connection
      $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
      // Check connection
      if ($conn->connect_error) {
             die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }


      if($_POST["doload"]=="doload"){
        $target_dir = "forms/";
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
        //echo "File Name:" . $target_file . "<br>";
        $uploadOk = 1;
        $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        // Check if file already exists
        if (file_exists($target_file)) {
             $message="Sorry, file already exists.<br>";
             $uploadOk = 0;
          }
        // Check file size
        if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
            $message="Sorry, your file is too large. <br>";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        // Allow certain file formats
        if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" && $imageFileType != "pdf" ) {
            $message= "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.<br>";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
        if ($uploadOk == 0) {
            $message= $message . "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.<br>";
        // if everything is ok, try to upload file
        } else {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
                $message = "The file " . basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded. <br>";
        //echo $message;
        $title=$_POST['title'];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO forms (Name, Path)
        VALUES ('" . $title . "', '" . $target_file . "')";

        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            //echo "New record created successfully";
        } else {
            //echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }

        header("Location: upload.php?message=" . $message . "demo_form_get");
            } else {
                $message = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file. <br>";
        header("Location: upload.php?message=" . $message . "");
            }
        }    
        }

    ?>
```

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and you are simply assuming that uploads never fail. That is very bad practice.

Comment: @MarcB I will be sure to add the mysqli_real_escape_string() once this problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do redirects, but there is no magic in it. Why not make your upload a function (a class would be better) and include the function on `upload.php` page?:

**functions/function.Database.php**

```
    // Making a database class makes more sense but, here a function is better
    // than what you are doing currently with your connection because you can call
    // it as a contained element
    function Database($servername = "localhost",$username = "**********",$password = "**********",$dbname = "***********")
        {
            // Create connection
            $con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
            // Check connection
            if ($con->connect_error)
                die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
            else
                return $con;
        }
```

**functions/function.UploadFile.php**

```
    // Create your upload function
    // You could feed the database in as an argument
    // then you don't have to recreate the database connection
    function UploadFile($settings = false)
        {
            $target_dir     =   (!empty($settings['target_dir']))? $settings['target_dir'] : "forms/";
            $iName          =   (!empty($settings['input']))? $settings['input'] : "fileToUpload";
            $filter         =   (!empty($settings['filter']) && is_array($settings['filter']))? $settings['filter'] : array("jpg","jpeg","gif","png");

            if(!is_dir($target_dir))
                mkdir($target_dir,0755,true);

            $filename       =   trim(basename($_FILES[$iName]["name"]));    
            $target_file    =   str_replace("//","/",$target_dir.$filename);
            $imageFileType  =   strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

            // Check if file already exists
            if(file_exists($target_file))
                 $error[]   =   array("error"=>true,"details"=>"Sorry, file already exists.");

            // Check file size
            if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000)
                $error[]    =   array("error"=>true,"details"=>"Sorry, your file is too large.");

            // Allow certain file formats
            if(!in_array($imageFileType,$filter))
                $error[]    =   array("error"=>true,"details"=>"Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.<br>");

            if(!empty($error))
                return $error;

            // if everything is ok, try to upload file
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$iName]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
                    $error[]    =   array("details"=>"The file " . basename($filename). " has been uploaded.");

                    //echo $message;
                    $title  =   trim(preg_replace('/[^0-9A-Za-z\-\_]/','',$_POST['title']));
                    $title  =   (!empty($title))? $title : date("YmdHis").uniqid();

                    // Create database connection
                    $conn   =   Database();
                    // You should escape or use bind parameters
                    // I am just converting for ease...
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO forms (Name, Path)
                    VALUES ('".htmlspecialchars($title,ENT_QUOTES) . "','".htmlspecialchars($target_file,ENT_QUOTES)."')";
                    $error[]    =   ($conn->query($sql))? array("details"=>"New record created successfully") : array("error"=>true,"details"=>"Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error);

                }
            else
                $error[]    =   array("error"=>true,"details"=>"The file " . basename( $_FILES[$iName]["name"]). "failed to upload.");

            // Just return the error message(s)
            return $error;
        }
```

**upload.php**

```
session_start();
// Include the database connection
include_once("functions/function.Database.php");

// Process file upload 
if(!empty($_POST['doload'])) {
        // Include the upload function
        include_once("functions/function.UploadFile.php");
        // Get the result back so you can show results to user
        $errors = UploadFile();
    }

// Use your database function here
$conn   =   Database(); ?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="nav"></div>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="content update">
    <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION["logedin"]) && $_SESSION["logedin"] == "true") {
            $pID    =   (is_numeric($_POST["ID"]))? $_POST["ID"]:false;

            if($pID != false) { 
                    $sql    =   "SELECT * FROM content WHERE ID=".$pID;
                    //echo $sql;
                    $result =   $conn->query($sql);

                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
                            $title  =   $row["title"];
                            $body   =   $row["body"];
                            $id     =   $row["ID"];
                        }
                }

            $breaks = array("<br />","<br>","<br/>","<br />","&lt;br /&gt;","&lt;br/&gt;","&lt;br&gt;");
            //$title = str_ireplace($breaks, "\n", $title);
            //$body = str_ireplace($breaks, "\n", $body);  
            //echo $body;
            echo strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_GET['message'],ENT_QUOTES));
         }

        // Run through errors
        // You can change the upload function to report differently
        // I just did a simple error return method
        if(!empty($errors)) {
                foreach($errors as $errArray) { ?>
                <div style="background-color: <?php echo (isset($errArray['error']))? "red":"green"; ?>" />
                    <?php echo $errArray['details']; ?>
                </div>
                <?php
                        $errArray   =   array();
                    }
            }
    ?>
            <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              Name file:
              <!-- You are missing an "=" here -->
              <input type="text" name="title">
              Select file to upload:
              <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
              <input type="hidden" name="doload" value="doload">
              <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="row2">
            <h2></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="row2">
            <div class="contentbubble">
                <h2 id="demo"></h2>
                <p id="demo2"></p>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried to make an edit but someone rejected it. $_POST['doupload'] will always return empty because It should be $_POST['doload'] because the sender is <input type="hidden" name="doload" value="doload">

Comment: I approved it, it looks like it should now, no?

Comment: Did you try the script (with that changes) to see if it worked for you? Oh forget it, I see you marked it as answered.

Comment: Ok edited. There is an edit in the top processing part as well as in the bottom above the form to display the errors.